# PHP CLI : pdo_pgsql not present

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp

I've browsed nearly all the similar questions but can't seem to find a proper answer for my install. 
I've reinstalled my computer and i'm trying to enable pdo_pgsql in php-cli. 
I'm on windows 10 and installed wampserver64 which is fine to work with.

I usually work with cakePHP as a framework and Postgre for database.

In Cake PHP you can use console to "bake" anything.

While trying to bake some models i ran into a dependency problem regarding bake.

pdo_pgsql extension is enabled in the PHP main php.ini but it's not loaded in php-cli mode which results in the cake bake error.

---

Here's the result of php --ini command :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.33\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

---

Here's the result of php -m command :

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

---

Here's the result of the php --ri pdo_pgsql command :

```
php --ri pdo_pgsql
Extension 'pdo_pgsql' not present.
```

---

Quick recap of my install :

```
Windows 10
Wampserver64 
POSTGRESQL 9.6
PHP 7.0.33
APACHE 2.4.4
```

I've checked different solutions like adding "libpq.dll" from postgresql bin directory via LoadFile in httpd.conf , i've also tested loading "libpq.dll" from php dir in the same file with no results so far.

Can anyone point me to a direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the extensions in php.ini and 
edit `httpd.conf` and add at the top of all the LoadModule lines the following:

```
LoadFile "actual_path_of_libpq.dll"
```

Restart the server and see it works or not.

check it  in `phpinfo()`

Comment: is it the path from  libpq.dll from the Postgresql install folder or php folder i have to copy ? 

Thanks for your message, will try both right now ;)

Comment: it will be something  like D:/...Postgres.../bin/libpq.dll

Comment: in phpinfo() i could already see postgresql driver enabled , it's for php cli that i can't seem to have it working.

Comment: try this one 

LoadFile "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/libpq.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working by having both fullpath as stated by Md Shifatul Islam and enabling extensions in php.ini.

i've also edited wampmanager.conf so that phpCliVersion matches the version i'm using which is "7.0.33" : phpCliVersion ="7.0.33"

Thanks to Md Shifatul Islam for his help, i've uvoted your answer but as i'm <= 15 reputation it doesn't show.